# How can i use RTL SDR libs for Android and QT creator?

Tags: android, c++, c, qt

i want to ask how can i use the rtl-sdr C libraries with the QT creator for an android App. Do you know how can i do that ? I use QT/C++ as language.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use rtl-sdr c native library in your Android app, you have to use the JNI techinque and add native support in your Android app project. You should download android ndk and start work with it. For more information, reference [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Comment: Can you help me to write the android.mk file ?

Comment: @xmaze you can refer the documents under `docs` of the ndk to learn how to write your own Android.mk

Comment: But the rtl-sdr libs needs also libusb, how can i do that, need to compile the libs together?

Comment: Yes, you can add libusb to `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` when you build rtl-sdr libs.